# Один сервер для websockets и http python3

Tags: python, http, websocket

Как создать один сервер для websockets и для http, используя разные handlers ? И возможно ли это ?
Хочу написать авторизацию по http, а дальше приложение бы подключалось по websockets например

Comment: handlers чего? Какой фреймворк/библиотека используется?

Comment: использую websockets 6.0, asyncio
handlers - ну обработчики для запросов

Comment: Выбранная вами библиотека специализирована только на обслуживании websocket. Вам придётся либо параллельно городить web-сервер на другой библиотеке, либо не изобретать велосипед и взять aiohttp, который может обслуживать и то, и другое.